# Get headers from @RequestHeader vs HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What's the difference between read header data from `@RequestHeader` annotation vs `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of using Spring `@RequestHeader` is that it will automatically throw an exception like
**HTTP Status 400 - Missing request header 'X' for method parameter of type**, if the header is NOT sent in the input request (by setting `required=true`). An example usage shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String users(@RequestHeader(required=true)String myHeader, Model model) {
    //your Code
}
```

You can also set the default value for the header if you use `@RequestHeader`, you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html)

**We need to manually check the condition for header value `!=null`, throw the exception or set the default value, if you use `HttpServletRequest`, which will make your code verbose.**

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in Performance. It is more convenient to use `@RequestHeader` than `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`.

This is similar to `@RequestParam` and `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`.

Spring has done the work of converting the request Headers, Parameters to method Parameters so that you can avoid boilerplate code.

There is a Spring written `MethodArgumentResolver` named `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver` which in fact uses `HttpServletRequest.getHeader()` to get the header.

Comment: Is there any Spring version limitation to @RequestHeader ?

Comment: Yes it is available from Spring MVC 3.0 only.