# How do i access the http header in rest API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, collections

i'm using the @Request header to access the header , when i'm running , i found that i'm unable to access the values of header using map function, when i try to print the value of headers.get("externalId") it return null, even when i'm passing the value of externalId in postman. can anyone please describe , how can i access the http header and use the specific value to pass them in a function.
And another thing when , i tried to print whole header , System.out.println(header), its printing ,the whole header.

```
 @GetMapping("transactionDetails")
            TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers){
                if(headers.containsKey("externalId"))
                return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(headers.get("externalId");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to get from "HttpServletRequest". And `request.getHeader("HEADER_NAME")`

```
GetMapping("transactionDetails")
            TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@HttpServletRequest request){

 String externalId = request.getHeader("externalId");

.
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong to get headers by using **@RequestHeader**.

I can get all my headers normally, including a 'externalId' header.

This is console from my Postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evpU1.png)

And this is my System.out.println of the Map headers from SpringBoot console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWGZo.png)

Everything is working fine. 
Maybe check your spelling ? 
If it wasn't spelling issue, check Postman console and make sure what Request Headers does it sends out.

And sorry for not having enough reputation yet to show image directly.

Comment: sir, i'm getting request header from postman, because when i tried to print it out on console it's printing the whole header, but when i individually tried to access the value like System.out.println(headers.get("externalId"), it prints null for the externalId, even though its showing the value in complete header. what i want to do is if(headers.containsKey("externalId")){ findDetails("exteranlID")} , but i'm unable to access the key value indiviually and when passing their values , but i'm able to print them on console individually.

Comment: @PrinceBhati  can you paste your postman view and also the code from SpringBoot you have now ?    I can both print out the whole headers map and also print specific header by using **headers.get**.

Comment: I also try your code with simply modify it to return a string, which return the 'externalId' value from the header if it contains in http headers, or else return "NOTHING" like below code.   `@GetMapping("/transactionDetails")  <br>
    String getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers){  
        if(headers.containsKey("externalId"))  return headers.get("externalId");  return "NOTHING";  
    }`  Everything works fine.

Comment: thx for your reponse , i've used the above method , it is working fine , now i'm focusing on other issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983166/how-to-do-write-working-jpa-query-for-the-below-the-code-in-sping-boot/73983221?noredirect=1#comment130630807_73983221), can you please take a look upon it.

Comment: Ok , But still it's better to use @RequestHeader than directly using '@HttpServletRequest ' to get headers because it helps decrease making your code verbose.  Check this article here [Get headers from '@RequestHeader ' vs '@HttpServletRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40707673/12973717)

Comment: thx for your reponse, i'll improve my code after i would successful implement my bussiness logic.

Comment: i want to use request header as you mentioned earlier . i could have any of three fields in my header or i can say one can access details using any of three parameters. given 1) externalId 2) clientId 3) merchantIt +userId. so first we would check , are these fields present in header or not, then we gonna pass the values of the id which we recieve in the header . So please can tell me how we gonna do that. i've tried before it  was'nt working .