# How to do write working jpa query for the below the code in sping boot

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity,Integer>{

   @Query("SELECT * FROM TransactionEntity WHERE TransactionEntity.externalId = :externalId")
   TransactionEntity findAllByExternalId(@Param("externalId") String externalId);
}
```

when i run above code i get

> error : antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: *

i want to return the TransactionEntity , which have the given externalId .
when i used the native query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM transaction_entity  WHERE transaction_entity.external_Id = :external_Id",nativeQuery = true)
```

my code is compiling withour error , but when i tried to retrieve the data using postman. i got this error

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for
> entity:  :
> TransactionService.transactionService.modal.TransactionEntity

Comment: Please do not edit your question to make it a different one. @artiomi answered your question. You should upvote and accept their answer. If you have new questions please ask them as a new question. 

The JPA spec https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a18 clearly states that JPA entities need a no-arg constructor:
"The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected."

Comment: @Jens Schauder, i'm Sorry , i did'nt know about that, i'll be careful next time.

Comment: That's ok. SO has tons of rules that sometimes feel rather strict. But they help making it the best source for answers for developers. Enjoy your time here.

Comment: @JensSchauder , you are completely right , i'm new here , and also newbie in the spring-boot or Java.

Comment: jeansSchauder i've resolved the issue . Intially @nonArgConstructor, was also not working , then i find that we cant alone use it with builder pattern, then i have to use AllArgsConstructor too.

Comment: @JensSchauder, sir . i did ask one question i'm unable to find its answer , please could you answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019085/how-to-read-header-using-request-header-in-spring-boot-and-passing-the-values-t/74019664#74019664

Answer (score 2):

try to use query with alias

```java
@Query("SELECT te FROM TransactionEntity te WHERE TransactionEntity.externalId = :externalId")
TransactionEntity findAllByExternalId(@Param("externalId") String externalId);
```

Comment: now getting this error   Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract(repository method name)

Comment: try renameing method to `findByExternalId`

Comment: Again getting the same error:"Validation failed for query for method public abstract TransactionService.transactionService.modal.TransactionEntity TransactionService.transactionService.repository.TransactionRepository.findByExternalId(java.lang.String)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public " .    But before that i used the native query. Then it was compiling fine , but not returning the data .

Comment: Can you show repository, service and entity clases?

Comment: thx sir, for your response , i've resolved the issue , its working fine , now.