# how to read header using @Request header in spring-boot and passing the values to other funtions

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

i want to read header using @Request herader. below is my controller class. I used the map for reading my header, now i want to check if my header contains the any of these three ids

> external id or client id or user ID+ merchant Id

**here is my controller class i was using contains method to check if header contains specific key or not, but it returns null, same with when i used get method to print the value of specific key.**

```
@RestController
public class TransactionController {
    @Autowired
    TransactoinService transactionService;

    @PostMapping
    TransactionResponse  createTransaction(@RequestBody TransactionRequest transactionRequest){
        return transactionService.createTransaction(transactionRequest);
    }
    @GetMapping(value="/transactionDetails")
    TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> header){
         System.out.println(header);
         return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(header.get("externalId"));
    }
}
```

when i run above code in postman this getmapping is not passing the value into the function, even though when i try to print the header its printing the value of externalId into header.
**here is the output of above code**

```
{externalid=b5eccae2-b6c1-4d17-987e-1849542df2a3, user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.29.2, accept=*/*, cache-control=no-cache, postman-token=07f367c4-e875-40ef-ab9b-5fd6d783d307, host=localhost:8080, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, connection=keep-alive}
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM transaction_entity  WHERE transaction_entity.external_Id = ?
```

[image: here it is image of postman status when i send the vaulues using headers]

i'm haveing above issue earlier too, but then i tried getmapping with httpservletRequest, then i find my other code have no problem because everything is working fine. now i'm again trying to implement the getmapping with reqestheader becuase @request header is good to use when try to read header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading header values with `@RequesHeader` you have to provide header name as annotation value. For details you can look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader)

```
 @GetMapping(value="/transactionDetails")
  TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader("externalid") String externalid){
     System.out.println(externalid);
     return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(externalid);
    }
```

Or you can pass `HttpEntity` as method parameter and read headers value from it. More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity)

```
 @GetMapping(value="/transactionDetails")
  TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity){
     System.out.println(requestEntity.getHeaders());
     return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(requestEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("externalId"));
    }
```

Comment: Sir, what about the others two ids ->clientreferenceId ->user+merchantId. i can get any of these two including externalId, that's why i did used the map , so that i can get to know about what type of key i'm getting. your method would work only when i'm sure that i would get only externalId. i read it from here , sir. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers

Comment: You're right for getting specific headers with `@RequestHeader` you need to define any of them as new method param `@RequestHeader("externalid")`, `@RequestHeader("clientreferenceId")`, etc. But as an alternative you can get all the headers from `HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity` parameter.

Comment: why we can use the getDetails(@Requestheader Map<String,String> header) to get all the headers , bcz i've seen it using somewhere , but i could'nt implement here. Can you please tell me how  can i implement it using only request header.

Comment: I guess there is a typeo, you try to get `externalId` with capital **I** while in controller you actually got `externalid` with lower **i**

Comment: but sir, i did write externalId in postman , so postman is sending it with externalid. not me.

Comment: For accessing header value in case insensitive way try to use `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders` as method parameter instead of `Map`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248728/discussion-between-prince-bhati-and-artiomi).